# AttributeError: '_BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'class_indices'

Tags: python-3.x, class, tensorflow2.0, attributeerror, tf.keras

I am trying to load a dataset to Tensorflow like this:

```
img_height= 220
img_width= 220
batch_size= 64
train_ds= tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    validation_split= 0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height,img_width),
    batch_size= batch_size
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    validation_split= 0.2,
    subset='validation',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height,img_width),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    shuffle=False
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    test_path,
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height,img_width),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    shuffle=False
)
```

`

and then i got this output:

```
Found 8005 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 6404 files for training.
Found 8005 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 1601 files for validation.
Found 2023 files belonging to 2 classes.
```

when i tried to get class:

```
class_indices = {}
for key in train_ds.class_indices.keys():
    class_indices[train_ds.class_indices[key]] = key

print(class_indices)
```

`

this is what i have get:

```
AttributeError: '_BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'class_indices'
```

how to access the classes in that data train?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error is - the `class_indices` parameter is not available in [image_dataset_from_directory()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) API. The `class_indices` parameter can be used only when datasets are imported using `flow_from_dataframe()` or `flow_from_directory()` APIs.

You can use `class_names` parameter to fetch the classes of the dataset while using `image_dataset_from_directory()`

**Please check this code:**

```
class_names  = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
```